# Winter '19 We can't find a Quick Text called 'Data sheet needed’ with the correct values

Tags: administration, admin, winter19

So I was doing the maintenance for 2019 and for some reason it won't accept my input.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/admin_cert_maintenance_winter19/get-handson-with-quick-text

I followed all the instructions to a T, and it keeps telling me "We can't find a Quick Text called 'Data sheet needed’ with the correct values." Even though all the values I entered are the exact same ones they list on the instructions.

I tried looking for help on the salesforce website but I didn't get any answers that actually solved the issue.

Quick text is enabled.

I created a Quicktext and named it "Data sheet needed".
I gave it the message "Please send a data sheet".
Set Category to "None".
And it's only selected channel is "Task".

Then I created a new case, with the status of "New".
Gave it an origin of "Phone" and a subject "Materials".

I then created a task from the related section of the case I just made and set its subject to be "Info Needed".
It's priority was also set to "Normal".
And finally, I applied the quick text to the comment section of the task.

So I'm at a complete loss on what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SFSE.

Generally we try to avoid giving direct answers to Trailhead questions as that goes against the spirit of Trailhead. If you had something like a coding challenge and provided sample code with a specific error message we could definitely provide **advice**.

In the event that you did find a bug within Trailhead, we are not Trailhead technical support. We don't have the ability to resolve the bug. on the right hand side of the Trailhead there is a "Questions, Feedback, or Help" button that will take you to a page containing a "Contact Us" link you can use to report the bug.

**The most important thing for you to remember with Trailhead** is that it is a learning tool. Generally, if what you did works in your sandbox and delivers the expected result, there is nothing stopping you from moving on to the next trail. There are a limited number of cases in which the points or badges on Trailhead offer real value (partners for instance benefit from this). Even in these instances, the points you'll lose on one module will be fairly negligible.

Don't stress yourself over fake internet points.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, it was an issue with the trailhead itself where you need to run it in incognito mode for it to work.